# Sending uploaded file to resque worker to be processed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, resque

I just started using resque to do some processing on some very large files in the background, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass a file to a resque worker. I use rails to handle the file upload, and rails creates an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` object for each file uploaded from the form.

How do send this file to a resque worker? I tried sending a custom hash of just the pathname of the temporary file and original filename, but I can't reopen the temporary file in the resque worker anymore (just a normal `Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory`) because rails seems to delete that temporary file after the request ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Http::UploadedFile`isn't accessible once the request finishes.  You need to write the file somewhere (or use s3 as temp storage).  Pass resque the path to the file that you wrote.

Comment: Seems like the only way. I just didn't want to handle the moving of the file before processing and the deleting afterward. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I just spent two days trying to do this and finally figured it out. You need to Base64 encode the file so that it can be serialized into json. Then you need to decode it in the worker and create a new

`ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`

Here's how to encode and pass to resque:

```
// You only need to encode the actual file, everything else in the 
// ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object is just string or a hash of strings

file = params[:file] // Your ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object 
file.tempfile.binmode
file.tempfile = Base64.encode64(file.tempfile.read)

Resque.enqueue(QueueWorker, params)
```

And Here's how to decode and convert back to an object within your worker

```
class QueueWorker
    @queue = :main_queue

    def self.perform(params)
        file = params['file']
        tempfile = Tempfile.new('file')
        tempfile.binmode
        tempfile.write(Base64.decode64(file['tempfile']))

        // Now that the file is decoded you need to build a new
        // ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile with the decoded tempfile and the other
        // attritubes you passed in.

        file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(tempfile: tempfile, filename: file['original_filename'], type: file['content_type'], head: file['headers'])

        // This object is now the same as the one in your controller in params[:file]
    end
end
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this, unless you're sure that your files will never be greater than a few hundred KB.  Writing the file to disk/s3/etc and passing that path to the Resque job is the proper way to handle this.

Comment: Definitely agree with @pnomolos that this isn't good for large files, but it's a clever hack if you're dealing with small files (e.g. 5-10KB CSV) where it's not worth the hassle of uploading them to S3 and then re-downloading them when you need them.